# Searching parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My program is designed to take input from a file containing a list of titles and authors. The file looks like so:

```
title
associated author
next title
associated author
etc.
```

The problem I'm having is with my showBooksByTitle and showBooksByAuthor functions. Right now this code returns only exact matches and also prints an empty newline and a new line with some spaces and a ().

Of course any help is greatly appreciated. This is my first year programming. I've included the whole code just to be safe that I'm not leaving out anything that could be the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Book {
    string title;
    string author;
};

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
Book books [ARRAY_SIZE];

int loadData (string);
void showAll (int);
int showBooksByAuthor (int, string);
int showBooksByTitle (int, string);

int main() {
    //Declare variables
    string pathname;
    string title;
    string name;
    string word;
    int count;
    char response;

    //ask user for pathname
    cout << "What is the path of the library file? ";
    cin >> pathname;
    cout << endl;
    count = loadData(pathname);

    //input data into arrays
    loadData(pathname);
    cout << endl << count << " records loaded successfully." << endl << endl;

    //Show user menu
    cout << "Please enter Q to Quit, A to search for the Author, T to search for the Title, "
    << endl << "or S to Show all: ";
    cin >> response;

    switch(response) {
        case 'q':
            break;
        case 'Q':
            break;
        case 'a':
            cout << endl << "Please enter author's name: ";
            cin >> name;
            showBooksByAuthor(count, name);
            break;
        case 'A':
            cout << endl << "Please enter author's name: ";
            cin >> name;
            showBooksByAuthor(count, name);
            break;
        case 't':
            cout << endl << "Please enter all or part of the title: ";
            cin >> title;
            showBooksByTitle(count, title);
            break;
        case 'T':
            cout << endl << "Please enter all or part of the title: ";
            cin >> title;
            showBooksByTitle(count, title);
            break;
        case 's':
            cout << endl;
            showAll(count);
            break;
        case 'S':
            cout << endl;
            showAll(count);
            break;
        default:
            cout << endl << "Invaled input, please try again: ";
            break;
    }

    //pause and exit
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int loadData(string pathname) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    ifstream library;

    //open file, if not successful, output error message
    library.open(pathname.c_str());
    if (!library.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //reads title and author from file into designated string
    //this is assuming title comes first and author comes after
    while(!library.eof()) {
        getline(library, books[i].title);
        getline(library, books[i].author);
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void showAll (int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << books[i].title << " (" << books[i].author << ")" << endl;
    }
}

int showBooksByAuthor(int count, string name) {
    int found;
    for(int n = 0; n < 28; n++) {
        found = name.find(books[n].author);
        if(found != string::npos) {
            cout << endl << books[n].title << " (" << books[n].author << ")" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int showBooksByTitle (int count, string title) {
    int found;
    for(int n = 0; n < 28; n++) {
        found = title.find(books[n].title);
        if(found !=string::npos) {
            cout << endl << books[n].title << " (" << books[n].author << ")" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this code reads from a text file and there are 28 books listed in the text file.I would attach the file but I don't see any option to do so here. I can paste it though

Comment: Shouldn't you be saving the return value from `loadFile` and use that as n argument to the other functions? Hard-coding "magic numbers" are considered bad. Think about what will happen when the file is edited do _not_ contain 28 entries.

Comment: The professor won't be looking for this code to be flexible in that way but that is an excellent point that I will be mindful of in the future. I appreciate you bringing it to my attention! I guess essentially what I am having trouble with is the bookbytitle and bookbyauthor functions. Right now this code returns only exact matches and also prints an empty newline and a new line with some spaces and a (). Do you see where I went wrong there? I can't seem to nail it down : /

Comment: @Roee please do not add the "homework" tag to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected output is because you read the data file wrong. A streams EOF flag is not set until *after* you tried an operation on the stream, so your loop iterates one to many times.

Change the loop in `loadData` to this:

```
while(getline(library, books[i].title) && getline(library, books[i].author))
    i++;
```

This uses the fact that `std::getline` return the stream, and that a stream can be used as a true/false value.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense! Do I still need the return i; then?

Comment: @Jason How else would you know how many entries you loaded? It's either that (returning `i + 1`) or using `std::vector` (which I would recommend).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was already pointed out by Joachim. I'd like to add a few review comments:

1. C++ has a variable length array, the `std::vector`. It also has a linked list and other containers. So don't make the books a fixed array but use some standard container.
2. Iterate things with iterators, not indices. For arrays pointer is iterator (C++11 has `end()` function to get pointer just past the end of array; it is trivial to write yourself in C++03, but you shouldn't be using plain old arrays anyway).
3. You are looking for the book name/title in the input string. You should be doing it the other way around if you want substring matches.

Comment: That is a great tip, thank you for that and I will be sure to bear that in mind. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use the vector for this assignment because we have not reviewed it in class yet.

Comment: Can you clarify 3. ? I followed the first two but I am not sure how to do found = name.find(books[n].author); the other way around.

Comment: @Jason Simple, `found = books[n].author.find(name);`

Comment: Thanks! I was scratching my head on that one!